# how to filter a list to remove the element with duplicated attribute in java?

Tags: java

I want to filter a list to remove the element with duplicated attribute, see code snippet below:

```
   public class People{
      string name;
      string priority;
      //...getter setter
    }

   list<People> peopleList = //...get a list of people
```

Here I want to show a list of people with unique name attribute , how to operate the `peopleList`  ? and also if there are several `People` object with same `name`, i want to check the `priority` to decide which one should be in the final unique list. hope i am clear.

Comment: You can use HashMap<String, People> = new HashMap<>();  the key is name and value is People instance, each time you check containsKey(), if exist compare the priority and then store the new value into the hashmap, if key exists, it will overwrite the old value. If it is possible, priority set to be integer will be easier for further comparison:)

Answer (score 0):

Just override `equals` method for `People` class and check equality of `name`. 
(I suppose here that `name` can not be null).

```
public class People{
  string name;
  string priority;
  //...getter setter

 @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof People) {
        return this.name.equals(((People) obj).getName());
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

After that, you will just have to do `yourList.contains(people)`.

- true: a People instance with the same name exists;
- false: there is no people with the same name.

And `yourList.indexOf(people)` will give you the position of the People with same name in the list.